# Problem on the wavelength of the electromagnetic radiation needed to break 1 mol of gas

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electromagnetic-radiation

**Problem.**
To break the bonds in 1 mol of Cl$_2$ we need E=243.4 kJ of energy. The bonds on this amount of gas can be broken by electromagnetic radiation of a certain length. Determine the wavelength.

**Solution.**
Firstly, there are 34 electrons in the molecule Cl$_2$. So in 1 mol of Cl$_2$, there are $n_e = 34\cdot N_A = 2.05\times 10^{25}$ electrons, where $N_A=6.022\times 10^{23}$ mol$^{-1}$ is Avogadro's constant. Now, the amount of energy needed for a single electron is (on average) $E_e = E/n_e = 1.19 \times 10^{-20}$ J.

We know that energy is related to the wavelength $\lambda$ by the relation
$$
E_e = h\frac{c}{\lambda},
$$
where $h=6.63\times 10^{-34}\, m^2 kg/s$ is the Planck constant and $c=3.00\times 10^8 \,m/s$ is the speed of light in vacuum. Thus

$$
\lambda = \frac{hc}{E_e} = 169\,nm.
$$
[Solution provided: 492 nm]

Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
I got the mistake thanks to @Domen (+10). I don't have to count all electrons but only those involved in the bonding. There is a single pair of electrons to be broken in a single chlorine molecule. In 1 mole of chlorine there are $N_A$ bonds, thus $n_e = N_A$. So the correct answer is $\lambda = 492$ nm.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange! You have a small conceptual mistake in your reasoning. Beware, there is a single covalent bond between the two chlorine atoms in $\ce{Cl_2}$. You should not calculate the number of electrons, you only need to know the number of bonds. So $n_e=1/N_A$ (where $N_A$ is the Avogadro's constant).

Comment: Oh I see, many thanks. As a side note: I haven't studied chemical bonds yet :-)

Comment: I meant $n_e = N_A$, of course.